# How to use { } Curly braces in java-script function to be generated by RPG-CGI pgm

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, ebcdic

How to write a RPG-CGI program to generate a HTML page which contains a java-script program having **function xxx() { aaaaaaaaaaaa; ssssssssss; }**. When written in using Hex code constant it is being changed to some other symbol in the actual html code in the browser.

Does EBCDIC character set contains **{** , **}**, **[** , **]** , **!** symbols.......if no,then how to use it in AS/400 RPG-CGI program ?

Comment: You're probably hard in your ways but without much work you can run PHP on an iSeries (zend core) also out of the box you should have the ability to deploy java war's on what I think they simply call the "Application Server" from what I understand it is a striped down web sphere application server.  I am not suggesting that RPG isn't a good language merely that it is WAY easier if you stand on the shoulders of giants and with an iSeries the two biggest in the web world are PHP and Java... What ever time you spend learning either will reap vast productivity returns in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running into a codepage conversion issue, which in brief means that the AS/400 does not produce the characters as expected by the recipient.   Try to run in code page 819 which is ISO-Latin-1

Comment: Thanks Mr. Anderson.  But I don't know how to use this code page 819 in AS/400? Can you please tell me on this...   Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Nirmal, sorry but I do not know that.  If nobody else does, I would suggest you ask the question on one of hte midrange lists.  See http://www.midrange.com/lists.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to look into using [CGIDEV2](http://www.easy400.net/cgidev2/start) though I would try Thorbjørn's option first.

Comment: I can't remember how do do that either.